# $k$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand this:

---

Let $L$ be the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax + b = 0$, where $A$ is an $(n-k) \times n$ real matrix with maximal rank $n-k < n$. Then the set $H$ of $x-y$ with $x,y \in L$ is a $k$-dimensional vector space.

---

The equation $Ax + b = 0$ has a solution (since $A$ has maximal rank), so $0 \in H$. But I don't think $H$ is closed under addition or scalar multiplication.

Comment: Without going through the details, I would have expected that $H$ was the null space of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a,b,c,d \in L$, and then to see that $H$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, use:

1. $(a - b) + (c - d) = (a + (c - d)) - b$
2. $\alpha ( a - b) = (a + (\alpha-1)(a - b)) - b$

where you need to show that $a + (c-d) \in L$ and $a + (\alpha - 1)(a- b) \in L$